# How to broadcast real-time data in SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, real-time

I have a timer in *Global.asax*, which calls a method to send current time to all clients through SignalR every 5 seconds:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<EventHub>();
        context.Clients.All.Send(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
```

my Hub class:

```
public class EventHub: Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage( message);
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {

    var context = $.connection.eventHub;
    context.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {

    alert("clock: " + message);
    };
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

no error, but no thing occurs on running application. what's my wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
context.Clients.All.Send(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
```

This will fire a method `Send` on the clients, it will not call

```
public void Send(string message)
{
    Clients.All.broadcastMessage( message);
}
```

Comment: You are listening  to a event ´broadcastMessage´ that will never trigger, you should listen to ´Send´ or correct your code